# How do numpy arrays change when passed to functions as parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

As you can guess by the title I'm not quite sure how to ask this question. Anyway the problem is the following:

I want to pass a numpy array as a parameter to a function, inside this function I want to make a copy of that array, then pass the array to another function manipulating the array and in the end replace the array with the copy.

```
...
arr = np.array([...])
arr_ocp = arr.copy()
func1(arr)
print np.array_equal(arr,arr_ocp) -> False
...

def func1(arr):
  arr_cp = arr.copy()
  func2(arr)
  print np.array_equal(arr,arr_cp) -> False
  arr = arr_cp
  print np.array_equal(arr,arr_cp) -> True

def func2(arr):
  ...
  arr[x:x+l,y:y+w] += np.array(...)
  ...
```

Now i did a few prints and it turns out that in func1 arr is the same at the beginning and the end, which I'd have expected.But if I do a print after func1(arr), arr is now the value of arr after func2. So why do the manipulations of func2 apply to arr but not the `arr = arr_cp`?

In hindsight it's probably better to pass the copy to func2 instead of the array itself, still I'd not expect this to happen like this. Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you explicit the positions of the `print`s with the actual output?

Comment: Added a lot more but those are probably the most important

Comment: can you include the code for func2 as well?

Comment: also the output of the `print`s, so I can understand the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between mutating and rebinding. When you do `arr = arr_cp`, all you're doing is rebinding the name `arr` to whatever is referred to by `arr_cp`. You don't in any way affect the object that was previously bound to `arr`.

However, when you do anything to `arr` itself - for example, `arr[0] = 'foo'` - that is a mutation, and changes the actual object. All names that are bound to that same object will continue to do so, so the changes will be visible to them all.

Comment: After having been alerted to this years later due to serial downvoting, I still find it interesting. Because it's not trivial, I first thought it would be about shadowing and that manipulating the parameter variable (by rebinding it to something else or changing it) would trigger a global change. But it's really because I manipulate the underlying object that the global changes are preserved while the mere rebinding is caught by shadowing.